# Copy text from an extjs htmleditor component to the clipboard with the W3C Clipboard API

Tags: javascript, extjs, clipboard, extjs5

I needed to copy text from an extjs htmleditor component to the clipboard and then paste it into a text document (word or oppenoffice).

It is possible to achieve this with the W3C clipboard API?

```
handler:function(){
        var one = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#OneItemId')[0].getValue();
        var two = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#TwoItemId')[0];

        document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){
            e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', one);
            e.preventDefault(); 
      });

        document.addEventListener('paste', function(e){               
            var values = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');
            two.setValue(values);
      });
    }
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cdi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot use [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) interface, because it **represents events** providing information related to modification of the clipboard, that is cut, copy, and paste events and since you want to copy on button click there is no such event.

Select and copy text in `htmleditor` component manually is abit tricky since its DOM representation is `<iframe>`.

I think solution is something like:

```
{
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Copy',
    handler:function(){
        var one = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#OneItemId')[0];
        var two = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#TwoItemId')[0];

        var editorFrame = one.inputEl.dom,
            editorFrameDocument = editorFrame.contentDocument || editorFrame.contentWindow.document;

        if(editorFrameDocument) {
            var documentSelection, selectionRange;

            // Select text in htmleditor iframe body
            // IE
            if (editorFrameDocument.body.createTextRange) {
                selectionRange = editorFrameDocument.body.createTextRange();
                selectionRange.moveToElementText(editorFrameDocument.body);
                selectionRange.select();
            } else if (window.getSelection) {
                documentSelection = editorFrameDocument.getSelection()        

                selectionRange = editorFrameDocument.createRange()
                selectionRange.selectNodeContents(editorFrameDocument.body);

                documentSelection.removeAllRanges();
                documentSelection.addRange(selectionRange);
            }

            // Copy selected text
            editorFrameDocument.execCommand('copy');
        }
    }

}
```

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1cek)

Just add some text to the editor, click "Copy" and paste wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks Serguei, your solution helps a lot.

Comment: Brilliant! Is there something for paste as well?